# Re arrange rows in a dataframe - R

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

UPDATED:

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
x <- data.frame("A" = c(15, 13.5, 12, 9.1), 
                "B" = c(13.6, 8.4, 6.7, NA), 
                "C" = c(8.5, 2.43, 1.23, NA),
                "D" = c(8.6, 6.43, 4.23, NA),
                "E" = c(7.5, 4.43, 3.23, NA))
```

And I need to arrange to something like this:

```
xR <- data.frame("A" = c(15, 13.5, 12, 9.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                 "B" = c(NA, 13.6, 8.4, 6.7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                 "C" = c(NA, NA, 8.5, 2.43, 1.23, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                 "D" = c(NA, NA, 8.6, 6.43, 1.23, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                 "E" = c(NA, NA, NA, 7.5, 4.43, 3.23, NA, NA, NA))
```

The logic is as follows:
I need to place the first value on col B where it is equal to or greater than the first value it meets in Col A and so on for Col B and Col C. I need to try automate it as my dataframe is huge.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is column A, B or C sorted?

Comment: Each column is sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try these two functions

```
align_proper <- function(df, at = c("first", "last"), offset = 0L) {
  df <- as.matrix(df)
  dr <- nrow(df)
  dc <- ncol(df)
  m <- cbind(t(df), NA_real_)
  pos <- is.na(m); m[pos] <- Inf
  pos <- cumsum(c(0L, pmin(
    max.col(m[-1L, 1L] >= m[-dc, ], match.arg(at)), 
    max.col(pos[-dc, ], "first")
  ) - 1L) + offset)
  pos <- pos - min(pos)
  outlen <- max(pos) + dr
  pos <- pos + 1L
  proto <- matrix(
    nrow = outlen, ncol = dc, 
    dimnames = list(NULL, dimnames(df)[[2L]])
  )
  as.data.frame(Reduce(function(out, i) {
    out[seq.int(pos[[i]], by = 1L, length.out = dr), i] <- df[, i]
    out
  }, seq_along(pos), proto))
}

align_top <- function(df) {
  collen <- max(colSums(!is.na(df)))
  as.data.frame(vapply(df, function(x) {
    x[!is.na(x)][seq_len(collen)]
  }, numeric(collen)))
}
```

We first use `align_top` to remove extra leading or trailing NAs (if any) for each column. You can skip this step if your actual data looks exactly like what you showed in your question, but we need to ensure a standardised input.

```
     A    B    C                  A    B    C
1 15.0   NA   NA             1 15.0 13.6 8.50
2 13.5 13.6   NA             2 13.5  8.4 2.43
3 12.0  8.4 8.50    ====>    3 12.0  6.7 1.23
4  9.1  6.7 2.43             4  9.1   NA   NA
5   NA   NA 1.23             
6   NA   NA   NA             
7   NA   NA   NA             
8   NA   NA   NA
```

`align_proper` then gives you the desired output

```
> align_proper(align_top(xR))
     A    B    C
1 15.0   NA   NA
2 13.5 13.6   NA
3 12.0  8.4 8.50
4  9.1  6.7 2.43
5   NA   NA 1.23
6   NA   NA   NA

> align_proper(align_top(x))
     A    B    C
1 15.0   NA   NA
2 13.5 13.6   NA
3 12.0  8.4 8.50
4  9.1  6.7 2.43
5   NA   NA 1.23
6   NA   NA   NA

> align_proper(data.frame("A" = c(1.23, 2.43, 6.5, NA), 
+                         "B" = c(6.7, 8.4, 8.9, NA), 
+                         "C" = c(9.1, 12, 13.5, 15)), "last")
     A   B    C
1 1.23  NA   NA
2 2.43  NA   NA
3 6.50 6.7   NA
4   NA 8.4   NA
5   NA 8.9  9.1
6   NA  NA 12.0
7   NA  NA 13.5
8   NA  NA 15.0
```

---

**Update**

I add one more argument `offset` in the function. Now you can do this

```
> align_proper(data.frame("A" = c(1.23, 2.43, 6.5, NA), 
+                         "B" = c(6.7, 8.4, 8.9, NA), 
+                         "C" = c(9.1, 12, 13.5, 15)), "last", -1L)
     A   B    C
1 1.23  NA   NA
2 2.43 6.7   NA
3 6.50 8.4  9.1
4   NA 8.9 12.0
5   NA  NA 13.5
6   NA  NA 15.0

> align_proper(data.frame("A" = c(1.23, 2.43, 6.5, NA), 
+                         "B" = c(6.7, 8.4, 8.9, NA), 
+                         "C" = c(9.1, 12, 13.5, 15)), "last", 3L)
      A   B    C
1  1.23  NA   NA
2  2.43  NA   NA
3  6.50  NA   NA
4    NA  NA   NA
5    NA  NA   NA
6    NA 6.7   NA
7    NA 8.4   NA
8    NA 8.9   NA
9    NA  NA   NA
10   NA  NA   NA
11   NA  NA  9.1
12   NA  NA 12.0
13   NA  NA 13.5
14   NA  NA 15.0
```

Comment: This worked magically @ekoam - however, I'd now like to have the value 6.7 (Col B, row 3) on row 2 (rather than row 3) and 9.1 (Col C, row 4) on row 4 and so on. Thanks so much for your help on this.

Comment: @user1655130 so one position ahead for each column?

Comment: Not quite right as the first value on col n should always be greater than the second value on Col n-1 - Does that make sense? If not, I'll try update my question. Thanks @ekoam

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused about your question. May you please give me a simple example illustrating the incorrect part? @user1655130

Comment: I updated the data in the question - hope it makes sense bow. Thanks @ekoam

Comment: Hi @user1655130, `align_proper(x, "first", 0L)` gives you the expected output, right? Can you show me the problem together with the code you have tried?

Comment: You are a genius @ekoam - worked great. I don't really understand it's workings but it works awesome. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an way to easily automate this, but you can do it in base R with the following algorithm:

```r
x <- data.frame("A" = c(1.23, 2.43, 6.5, NA), 
                "B" = c(6.7, 8.4, 8.9, NA), 
                "C" = c(9.1, 12, 13.5, 15))


x <- as.list(x)

for(i in 2:length(x)) {
  x[[i]] <- c(rep(NA, which.max(x[[i-1]][x[[i-1]] < x[[i]][1]])), x[[i]])
}

x <- lapply(x, function(y) c(y, rep(NA, max(sapply(x, length)) - length(y))))

as.data.frame(x)
#>       A   B    C
#> 1  1.23  NA   NA
#> 2  2.43  NA   NA
#> 3  6.50  NA   NA
#> 4    NA 6.7   NA
#> 5    NA 8.4   NA
#> 6    NA 8.9   NA
#> 7    NA  NA  9.1
#> 8    NA  NA 12.0
#> 9    NA  NA 13.5
#> 10   NA  NA 15.0
```

Comment: This works great for this dataset - when I apply it to mine, I get the following error: ```Error in rep(NA, which.max(x[[i - 1]][x[[i - 1]] < x[[i]][1]])) : 
  invalid 'times' argument ``` Any ideas on how to fix this? thanks

Comment: @user1655130 that would suggest that one of the columns has no values that are less than the smallest value in the column immediately to its right. (I can replicate the error by making `A = c(9, 10, 11, 12)` in the example data frame). It wasn't obvious from your problem description that this was a possibility, nor what you would want to happen in this scenario.

Comment: @user1655130 you would need to remove it in advance I guess. Like `for(i in 2:length(x)) { if(max(x[[i]], na.rm = TRUE)  < min(x[[i - 1]], na.rm = TRUE)) x[[i]] <- NA}; x <- x[-sapply(x, allNA)]`

Comment: Actually @Allan Cameron, on working on it, my df will be as follows: ```x <- data.frame("A" = c(15, 13.5, 12, 9.1), 
                "B" = c(13.6, 8.4, 6.7, NA), 
                "C" = c(8.5, 2.43, 1.23, NA))``` so there should always be values smaller for the majority of them. In the case that they are not, place them to the closest value - not sure if that is possible?

Comment: @user1655130 I thought all your columns were sorted, and in increasing order - is the opposite true?

Comment: Sorry @Allan Cameron, I since realised the opposite is actually true - really sorry about this. Will update question now. Your code still works however on this dataset.

Comment: @user1655130 It's fine. But now I'm confused. My code still works on your new example - it gives the expected output

Comment: yep me too @Allan Cameron, I dont really understand either to be honest

Comment: @user1655130 can you share a link to your actual data on a dropbox or anything? Otherwise difficult to know how to help. The solution I posted works on both the examples you posted, and if I can't replicate your error then...?